# Intersection of two planes through the origin [GStrang P129, 3.1.15(a)]

Tags: linear-algebra

> The intersecton for two planes through $(0, 0, 0)$ is probably a line but it could be a 
>   point.
>    $\Large{\color{red}{[}}$ It can't be the vector space that consists only of a zero vector. $\Large{{\color{red}{]}}}$

I don't perceive the red bracket. Don't the olive and grey plane in this sketch intersect only at the origin in orange?

[image]
This question precedes nullspace, rank, REF, $\mathbf{Ax = b}$, linear independence, span, basis, dimension, dimensions/theorems of the 4 subspaces, Orthogonality, Determinants, eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and linear transformations. Please omit them.

Comment: The intersection of two different planes that pass through the origin must be a line. Your diagram only shows a small portion of either plane. Their intersection is a line passing through zero.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thank you. I'm cognisant that planes in general are infinite, but can't I define the planes as above (to be finite) to be the small portions as drawn? Then what happens?

Comment: Well, then they won't be planes in the usual sense. If they are infinite in extent and pass through the origin them must either be the same or intersect along a line.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: @copper.hat: So was I correct in that the intersection of special finite planes (as above) can $= \mathbf{0}$? But intersection of infinite planes can never be $\mathbf{0}$? Could you please verify or refute this?

Comment: Well, when people talk about planes, they mean infinite planes. If two different planes pass through zero, they **must** intersect in a line (that passes through zero). You can always choose some smaller subset so that the intersection is $\{0 \}$.

Comment: I added something, hopefully that is what you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you deeply! I'll pore over it. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when people talk about planes in three dimensions, they mean a set of the form $P=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | n^T x = d\}$, where $n \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a fixed non-zero vector and $d \in \mathbb{R}$.

A plane is infinite in extent as $\ker n^T$ is two dimensional, and the point $x_0={d \over \|n\|^2} n \in P$, so $x_0+k \in P$ for any $k \in \ker n^T$.

If the plane passes through the origin, it is easy to see that the corresponding $d$ above must be zero.

The intersection of two planes that pass through the origin will be given by $L = P_1 \cap P_2$, where $P_k = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | n_k^T x = 0\}$.
We can write
$L = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 | n_1^T x = 0, n_2^T x = 0\} = \ker N^T$, where $N = \begin{bmatrix} n_1 &  n_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

If the planes are different (equivalently $n_1, n_2$ do not lie on the same line), then $n_1, n_2$ are linearly independent, and $\dim \ker N^T = 1$, hence $L$ is a line of infinite extent passing through the origin.

You can always choose subsets $S_1, S_2$ of $P_1, P_2$ so that $S_1$ and $S_2$ only intersect at the origin, but then $S_1,S_2$ will not be planes in the usual sense.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is using the following theorem:

Given a vector space $V$ and two subspaces $W_1,W_2$ You get that $$\dim(W_1\oplus W_2) = \dim W_1 + \dim W_2 - \dim(W_1\cap W_2)$$
where $W_1\oplus W_2=\mbox{span}\{W_1\cup W_2\}$ is the minimal subspace which contains both $W_1$ and $W_2$.

you can look at this as a linear algebra variant of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the reason we subtract $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)$ is to account for "counting" the shared subspace twice (once in $\dim W_1$ and once in $\dim W_2$).

Now, given two planes in $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ you may think of them as two dimensional subspaces we denote $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Now, if $W_1=W_2$ then their intersection is the plane, else $W_1\oplus W_2=V$ (why?) and from the above equation
$$3 = \dim V = \dim W_1 + \dim W_2 - \dim (W_1\cap W_2) = 4 - \dim (W_1\cap W_2)$$ hence $\dim W_1\cap W_2 = 1$, which geometrically means $W_1 \cap W_2$ is a line through the origin.

Comment: I agree that it is tempting to describe $dim W_1 + W_2 = dim W_1 + dim W_2 - dim W_1 \cap W_2$ as "the inclusion-exclusion principle".  But it is also dangerous to do so: inclusion-exclusion generalizes to more than two sets, and this formula (rather surprisingly) does not.  Also $\oplus$ is usually used only when $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If a plane P1 has equation $F=ax+by+cy=0$ and the equation of another plane P2 has equation $G=dx+ey+fz=0$ (note they both pass through the origin), then the points of their intersection correspond to solutions of the linear system $L: (F=0,G=0)$, which is a linear system with three variables and only two equations. Such a system will always have infinitely many solutions (over an infinite field of course).